# Solution for broken pin repair (SMD(SMT) components)

Tags: surface-mount, repair

While I was working with a [IS62WV51216BLL-55TLI](http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/62WV51216ALL.pdf), I broke off by chance a pin at the base near the component body. that's perfect! LoL!

[image: figure1]

It makes me to think about this question:

Can we fix such problems? I mean Can we make a connection between the board and the broken pin of the component?

A good news, fortunately there is just one broken pin. well I was thinking that by an thin L-shaped wire we can make a connection. how about this idea? something like this:

[image: figure2]

Do you have a better idea? I'm completely quiet and focused to hear your ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately I can say from experience this is possible. Use the finest wire you can get, within reason, AWG 40 is not too fine, and try to solder it on the flush stump with plenty of flux (and the wire pre-tinned). Once it passes a tug test, you can trim it and solder it to the PCB pad. Use a decent temperature-controlled iron, fine solder and liquid flux.

It won't be very reliable but it might get you through to Monday or Tuesday when the courier can arrive with a new part.

Comment: One source of fine wire is single strands from a highly flexible appliance linecord.

Comment: Sometimes when trying to solder to a stub lead, which can often be a pretty good challenge, it is necessary to use a sharp x-acto type blade to scrape away the plastic mold flash near the pin to get a few more mils of surface area to which to attach the soldered wire.